# Repeating headers doesn't work in SSRS 2012

Tags: sql, reporting-services, header, ssrs-2012

I have followed these instructions found in several places on the internet https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/repeating-freezing-column-headers-ssrs-tables/
to get the headers to repeat on every page and it doesn't work.  Are there any other suggestions for getting this to work?

First Page:

[image: Page 1 with Headers]

and the next page:

[image: Page 2 no Headers]

Comment: Are you still having an issue repeating the headers?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the next static column over (usually right below the first column in the advanced mode list) to repeat on next page as well. Sometimes this works. Otherwise, you might want to try generating a new table and it might work with the new one. SSRS is finicky with this for whatever reason.